# Cloud Functions for Firebase: how to read data from Database synchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I using Cloud Functions for Firebase to build HTTP endpoint. Inside this endpoint I am trying to read some data from Firebase Realtime Database synchronously by this method:

```
function getSomethingFromDbSynchronously (currency) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var db = admin.database();
        var ref = db.ref("someref");
        ref.orderByChild("somechild").equalTo("something").once("value", function (snapshot) {
            resolve(snapshot);
        });
    });
}
```

But it is doesn't works for me. My API route returns by the first return statement before this request to the DB ends. 
What am I do wrong ?

Comment: That's an asynchronous call. There's no reason to want it to be synchronous. It would be a mis-feature.

Comment: You can't.  Learn how to program appropriately with asynchronous calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks fine: you're creating a new promise and returning that from `getSomethingFromDbSynchronously()`. But the code that calls `getSomethingFromDbSynchronously()` will then need to wait for the promise to resolve, with something like:

```
getSomethingFromDbSynchronously("currency").then(function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

There is no way to make this synchronous, although you could look into the new `async` and `await` keywords, which simply make the above read as if it happens synchronously.

Note, that your code is a bit longer than needed. Since `once()` already returns a promise, you might as well return that directly:

```
function getSomethingFromDbSynchronously (currency) {
    var db = admin.database();
    var ref = db.ref("someref");
    return ref.orderByChild("somechild").equalTo("something").once("value");
}
```